# I asked 2 questions in 1 post, now I have 2 answers, each one answers another question, which one to accept?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer, too-broad

In 1 [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261119/intuitively-understand-why-the-poisson-distribution-is-the-limiting-case-of-the) I asked 2 questions. I asked them together, since they occurred together for me, even though in hindsight I could've asked them separately.

However, now I have an answer that answers my first question very well, and *another* answer that answers the second question very well.

Should I (one or more apply):

1. accept one of both?
2. have posted 2 questions in 2 posts?
3. answer the question myself, borrowing from, and mentioning, the other authors?
4. ask the authors of both answers to include their answer to the other question also?
5. do nothing?
6. wait for someone to answer both questions in a single answer?
7. do something else?

Comment: This is why we ask people to limit posts to one question!

Comment: It's not possible to accept both.

Comment: At this stage you should probably choose one to accept and then try to post one question per post in future.

Comment: And leave a comment for the other post to let the answerer know what happened.

Comment: You can't accept A and B; so a little arbitrarily you accept A; what some people then do is look for another answer by B that they like and can upvote. I too commend commenting with the flavour "I like your answer too".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Waiting for someone else step in and provide a complete answer there, when such answers already exist, but in different posts seems unlikely, besides a little bit counterproductive.

**Alternatively**, you can accept the answer to your main question, i.e., the question number 1, which is more closely tied with the question's title and; simultaneously edit that accepted answer (or leave a comment beneath it) to include a final sentence in it along the lines:

> Edit from @Ytsen de Boer (OP): question number 2 is [satisfactorily] answered at @xxx user.

This way, you can accept one answer and promote upvotes on both answers. Everybody wins.

---

> 1. Accept one of both? **A: Yes, but make sure to be clear the other answer, answered the second part of the question.**
> 2. Have posted 2 questions in 2 posts? **A: Yes, if you had not posted it yet.**
> 3. Answer the question myself, borrowing from, and mentioning, the other authors? **A: This is not productive to me; it would compete with the original answers, removing attention/credit/votes from them. If such answers were posted as comments, then, yes.**
> 4. Ask the authors of both answers to include their answer to the other question also? **A: No, if they did not answer the other part of the question, it is because they did not want to. Not that asking would hurt, but why ignoring the complementary existing answers?.**
> 5. Do nothing? **A: Given the amount of answers received, doing nothing would be quite frustrating.**
> 6. Wait for someone to answer both questions in a single answer? **A: Not productive.**
> 7. Do something else? **A: Not necessary, option 1 is fine.**

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

1. Accept the answer to your first question
2. Move your second question as a new question
3. Flag the answer to your second question asking to migrate the answer to your new question.

I think this is the best course of action to keep the website organized. Additionally people get their reputation if they care.

Comment: AFAIK we can't move answers between questions.

Comment: @Scortchi Stack Exchange should add this feature. Please support [Allow high rep users to migrate answers from one question to another](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40346/178179) and [Can moderators be allowed to move answers to other questions piecemeal?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147896/178179)

Comment: I don't like to change the nature of the question after people have already formulated answers to the original formulation. That will certainly lead to inconsistent threads and *a lot* of maintenaince hours for moderators.

Comment: @YtsendeBoer your title says "I asked 2 questions in 1 post, now I have 2 answers, each one answers another question" so it sounded to me like it was easily separable.

Answer (score -1):

The current situation is rather unfortunate, but it is how it is.

What to do in this situation seems to me rather straightforward:

Since you should not

1. accept an incomplete answer or
2. modify your question so as to make 1 answer fit

you have to leave the question open until someone answers it completely.